# Passing an object's Type in a call to a Generic

Tags: c#, generics

I've seen several other similar posts, but they don't seem to fit with my scenario.

I'm trying to create a set of deep Cloning methods to a set of objects that inherit from a base class.  I've created some sample classes that illustrate what I'm trying to do.

I've been reading through all the similar posts here and the MS documentation, but nothing seems to work.  Any suggestions on how to approach this would be appreciated.

The offending line of code in this is below.  Using typeof(c) is invalid and I cannot find any suitable way of replacing that with something that does work.

```
SubEvents = (IList<IFoo>) SubEvents.Select(c => c.Clone < typeof(c) > ()).ToList()
```

I cannot figure a way to pass the object's type to the Clone method.

```
public class MyFoo : IFoo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<IFoo> SubEvents { get; set; } = new List<IFoo>();

    public T Clone<T>() where T : IFoo, new()
    {
        var rtn = new T
        {
            Id = Id,
            SubEvents = (IList<IMyFoo>) SubEvents.Select(c => c.Clone < typeof(c) > ()).ToList()
        };
        return rtn;
    }
}

public class Bar: Foo, IBar
{
    public int Fred { get; set; }
    public int Betty { get; set; }

    public IEventQuestTimerChange Clone()
    {
        var rtn = base.Clone<Foo>();
        rtn.Fred = Fred;
        rtn.Betty = Betty;
        return rtn;
    }
}

public class Loader
{
    var IList<IFoo> MyList {get;set;} = new List<IFoo>();
    MyList.Add(new Foo());
    var bar = new Bar();
    bar.SubEvent.Add(new Foo());
    bar.SubEvent.Add(new Bar());
    MyList.Add(bar);

    var cloneList = MyList.Clone();
}
```

Comment: Well generic types need to be specified at compile time, whereas `typeof` checks the type at runtime, so this won't work. Why is `Clone` generic anyway? `IGameEvent` seems to be the same as `IMyFoo`.

Comment: From what I can see ( and for the rest of it assume ) `IMyFoo` inherits `IGameEvent`? It is my guess that you are supposed to be implementing `Clone` as an extension method

Comment: IGameEvent was a bit of hold-over code when I was trying to create the sample.  The actual code is quite large, so I wanted to cut it down to something more consumable.

Comment: Even after the edit: What is `IFoo`? is it an interface anything else inherits in the code you have given or is just another interface you want to convert to? This actually matters quite a bit

Comment: My bad, I had IMyFoo and IFoo.  They are all now IFoo.  IFoo is the interface for Foo.  IBar implements/extends IFoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, the reason you want to use a generic type in the clone method is so you can return the derived type, and not the base type.

One way to solve this would be to create a copy-constructor, and a virtual clone method that returns a object of the derived type. That way you should not need any generics to create a deep copy:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public int FooProperty { get; }
        public List<Foo> FooList { get; }
        public Foo()
        {
            // Regular Constructor
            FooList = new List<Foo>();
        }
        protected Foo(Foo other)
        {
            // Copy constructor
            FooProperty = other.FooProperty;
            FooList = other.FooList.Select(item => item.Clone()).ToList();
        }

        public virtual Foo Clone() => new Foo(this);
    }

    public class Bar : Foo
    {
        public int BarProperty { get; }
        public Bar()
        {
            // regular constructor
        }
        protected Bar(Bar other) : base(other)
        {
            // Copy constructor
            BarProperty = other.BarProperty;
        }
        public override Foo Clone() => new Bar(this);
        public virtual Bar CloneBar() => new Bar(this);
    }
```

Example:

```
        var root = new Foo();
        root.FooList.Add(new Bar());
        root.FooList.Add(new Foo());
        var clone = root.Clone();
        Console.WriteLine($"Root: {clone.GetType().Name} -> [{clone.FooList[0].GetType().Name}, {clone.FooList[1].GetType().Name}]");
```

Will write: "Root: Foo -> [Bar, Foo]"

Comment: The reason for the proposed solution I have is because I have 200+ types of classes that inherit from IFoo.  Those classes extend the Foo class.  Cloning them is easy.  It's the list of IFoo objects in Foo that creates the problem because I can't determine what type of object it is in order to call it's Clone method.  In an earlier comment I had mentioned that a solution is to have a method that creates hard casts to the parent object (or is it base object, I get the naming confused in my head at times) but that seems heavy handed.  I'm not clear how Item.Clone() solves the problem.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. The type of object it in the list should not matter, as long as it a clone method returning the same type. Then it is up to the implementation of the clone method to return a object of the correct derived type.

Comment: The problem is, when traversing List<IFoo> I can't call the parent's Clone method because my generic only sees is as an object of type Foo, instead of seeing as type Bar (or any other class that implements IFoo.

Comment: I've updated the code to better show what I'm trying to describe.  The Loader method shows how SubEvents can have a list of different types of objects.  The Clone call needs to call each object's Clone() method rather than the base Foo's Clone method.

Comment: the clone method is virtual and overridden, so if the object is Bar, clone will return a new Bar object. Added an example.

Comment: It's going to be a PITA to implement because this approach is very different from my own, but it appears to work perfectly.  I don't know why it was an absolute failure for me the first time I tried a similar approach.  Thank you for this.

Comment: Still, it's a shame that the generics method couldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cant pass a type into a generic like that and the only way to do it is using reflection.

Instead add an overload to `T Clone<T>(...` for `object Clone(Type type)`

Comment: I had tried to take that approach, but I never got it close to working.

Comment: The working only solution I can come up with (and it feels just so very wrong) is to have a method in the base class that identifies the object type inheriting it, casting the object to that type, and then calling that cast-object's Clone method.